# Get result from Python script after the script has finished?

Tags: python, docker

I have a python script that creates a map inside the docker container once the script has finished running:

```
/result
```

This is the map I want from the docker container.

How can I get the /result map from the docker container? The container seems to exist so fast after the script is done that I can't do a

```
docker cp
```

Right now I'm running my container with

```
docker run --rm imgTest --arg=hello --argTwo=world
```

but how can I get docker to copy over the /result directory to the host machine before it ends?

Comment: Have it print to standard output, and run with `docker run -t`?

Comment: well the result files can be quite large JSON objects. so I much rather get them to the host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the folder

```
docker run --rm -v /some/host/path:/result imgTest --arg=hello --argTwo=world
```

Comment: great, is it possible to add this to the Dockerfile or does it need to be in the run command?

Comment: This is a runtime parameter, not build-time, so therefore cannot be added to the Dockerfile